# Accessing address of a string in inline assembly in gcc

Tags: c, gcc, inline-assembly, uppercase, att

I have written the below assembly code to convert a string from lower case to uppercase, It's not completely working because i'm not able to access the address of a string that i'm converting. this code is not working why?

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  int convert(char *str)
  {
       char *ptr;
  __asm__ __volatile__ ( "movl (%1),%%ebx;"
                    "subl $1,%%ebx;"
                    "movl %%ebx,%0;"
            "REPEAT: addl $1,%%ebx;"
                    "testl %%ebx,%%ebx;"
                    "je END;"
                    "movzbl 0(%%ebx),%%ecx;"
                    "cmpl $97, %%ecx;"
                    "jb END;"
                    "cmpl $122,%%ecx;"
                    "ja END;"
                    "subb $32,0(%%ebx);"
                    "jmp REPEAT;"
              "END: movl %%ebx,(%0);"
                    :"=r" (ptr)
                    :"r"  (str)
                 );
   printf("converted string =%s\n", str);
 }

  int main()
  {
  int i;  
  char str[] = "convert";

  i = convert(str);
  return 0;

  }
```

Comment: What is your question? Please ask a question.

Comment: @FUZxxi: I'm not able to access the address of string, and above code is not working!

Comment: At which point are you assigning to `ptr` or `str`?

Comment: str is my input, so which is %1, I want the address of str to be in ebx, And final output is in ptr, basically ptr is just for output purpose. I want to change the characters to upper in str itself.

Comment: I would suggest you to write the logic you need in an assembly file on its own before integrating it as inline assembly. I'm not quite sure what you try to archieve with the code. Why do you move `*str` into `%ebx` in the first instruction? Why not `str`?

Comment: I got compiler error in doing so, 
initially i did like "movl %1,%%ebx;"     compiler error: Error: unsupported instruction `mov'

Comment: That's because you where compiling for amd64, not i386. On amd64, pointers have a size of 64 bits. Of course, `movl %rdi,%ebx` is not a valid instruction. You might want to compile for i386 with `cc -m32` instead.

Comment: Also, getting a compiler error does not mean you should randomly throw in indirections. Retrieve assembly with `cc -S` first and try to understand what assembly the compiler generates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64345/discussion-between-gmcode-and-fuzxxl).

Comment: In addition to the comments above, let me point out that you are changing the registers ebx and ecx without letting the compiler know.  If you are using these as scratch registers, list them in the "clobbers" section.  Also, since you are modifying the contents of str, you should be using the "memory" clobber.  If you plan on working with gcc's inline asm, you should check out their docs about it: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html

Comment: @David: Thank you for giving the doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution slightly different than above, Thanks FUZxxi for pointing it out. I should say that retrieving assembly helps in a great extent, it can be hard to understand but it gives you the actual problem.  I have written enough comments if somebody wants to understand what i'm trying to achieve.

```
/* code to convert from lower case to upper case */
int convert(char *str)
{
   __asm__ __volatile__ ( "movl %1,%%ebx;"  // Get the address of str
                "subl $1,%%ebx;"     
        "REPEAT: addl $1,%%ebx;"    
                "movl 0(%%ebx),%%edx"  // Move the contents to edx
                "movzbl %%dl,%%ecx;"   // moving last character to ecx
                "testl %%ecx,%%ecx;"   // compare if it's null
                "je END;"              
                "cmpl $97, %%ecx;"     
                "jb END;"
                "cmpl $122,%%ecx;"
                "ja END;"
                "subb $32,(%%ebx);"  // if its lower case, subtract 32
                "jmp REPEAT;" 
          "END:;"
                :           // No output specified
                :"r"  (str) //input
                :"ecx","edx" //clobbers
             );
  printf("converted string =%s\n", str);
}
```

Above code should work if you compile using "gcc -m32" option, if you are compiling for amd64. I encountered a problem doing that 
"fatal error: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory "

solution : Install this package: libc6-dev-i386

Comment: How ever this solution is not the efficient one, If you want to do it in quick time(mostly that's what we want) please use vector instructions.

Answer (score 1):

The code in the accepted answer seems to have a few problems:

- As written, this code does not compile (it references %1 when there is only 1 parameter), and it's missing a terminator on the 4th asm line.
- This code does not correctly handle strings like "aBc".
- This code does not use the "memory" clobber, even though it modifies memory.
- This code (still) modifies a register that is not clobbered (ebx).
- Doesn't work for x64.

How about something more like this:

```
char *convert(char *str)
{
   char *res = str;
   char temp;

   __asm__ __volatile__ (
         "dec %[str]\n"
      "REPEAT:\n\t"    
         "inc %[str]\n\t"
         "movb (%[str]), %[temp]\n\t"  /* Read the next char */
         "testb %[temp], %[temp]\n\t"
         "jz END\n\t"                  /* Is the char null */
         "cmpb $97, %[temp]\n\t"       /* >= 'a'? */
         "jb REPEAT\n\t"
         "cmpb $122, %[temp]\n\t"      /* <= 'z'? */
         "ja REPEAT\n\t"
         "subb $32, %[temp]\n\t"       /* Perform lowercase */
         "mov %[temp], (%[str])\n\t"   /* Write back to memory */
         "jmp REPEAT\n" 
      "END:\n"
         : [str] "+r" (str), [temp] "=r" (temp)
         : /* no inputs */
         : "memory"
   );

   /* Note that at this point, str points to the null. 
      str - res is the length. */

   return res;
}
```

This code:

- Uses fewer registers (2 vs 4).
- By using "=r" (temp), we are letting the compiler select the best register to use for scratch rather than forcing a specific register.
- Only reads the memory once (instead of twice).
- Returns a pointer to the string (instead of returning nothing?).
- IMO, using %[temp] and %[src] is slightly easier to read than %1.
- Using `\n\t` (instead of `;`) makes the output from `gcc -S` easier to read.
- This code modifies str (which is why it is listed as "+r").

Or if you really want to get fancy, write the code in 'c', and use `gcc -O2 -S` to see the output.